# Change Default Font in Xcode 8 Swift 3 IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Is there any way to change the default font of the Application from one place, not each view controller and not each element category??

for example in html and CSS, you can define the global font from CSS with one line of code.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I have edit my question

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its what you ask, but you can change all the fonts in your app in appDelegate. Will change all the fonts in the buttons, labels, etc.

you can do it creating a extension form UILabel like this

```
extension UILabel {

    var substituteFontName : String {
        get { return self.font.fontName }
        set { self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: self.font.pointSize) }
    }
}
```

then in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in your appDelegate you can call the variable and pass the name of the font you want, like this:

```
UILabel.appearance().substituteFontName = "Kyrial Sans Pro"
```

Comment: this will cause the app to crash in runtime with "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". You now need to add @objc to the var

Answer (score 0):

when you add the font to info.plist you already changed the default font of the Xcode , try to leave the UILabel Font as system Font and change only the style and run your app you will have what you want.